# Lattice Histogram multiplot with different layouts

Tags: r, parameters, histogram, lattice

I wanted to take a closer look at the distribution of RT-times on questions. To do so, I used lattice to make histrograms and depict them in one figure. I used the following settings:

```
histogram( ~ rt | pp,layout=c(6,4),data = data.frame,
       main=list(
         label="RT distribution per subject",
         cex=1.5),
       xlab=list(
         label="RT (s)",
         cex=0.75),
       ylab=list(
         label="Percentage occurence",
         cex=1.2),
       xlim=c(0,40),
       breaks = 10
)
```

In other words, I want the participants' data to be plotted on an x-axis from 0 to 40 seconds, divided into 10 bars. This is done for some sub-plot, but for many they use a different breaks. I added the figure. **Why does the function not use the same layout for every sub-plot?**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem. Instead of specifying the amount of break, you can specify an array with breaks as follows:

```
histogram( ~ rt | pp,layout=c(6,4),data = data.frame,
   xlim=c(0,40),
   breaks = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55)
)
```

or, more simply,

```
histogram( ~ rt | pp,layout=c(6,4),data = data.frame,
  xlim=c(0,40),
  breaks = seq(from=0,to=55,by=1)
)
```

Note, however, that the range must include **every** data point. For more see [C-Ran's page about Lattice's histrogram](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tigerstats/vignettes/histogram.html).

[image]